# Android: Can 3rd party activity access my application data?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching a third party app (AppC) using `startActivity()` and `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage()` API:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

and when I return from that app some features of my application stop working until I manually clear data of my application. If I use a different 3rd party app (AppK) - everything works just fine.

Is it possible that AppC does something to my application's data? What could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppC was deleting files in the shared (Downloads) folder, which my app relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that AppC does something to my application's data?

Probably not. The author of AppC probably does not know you exist, let alone to exploit any security holes in  your app to do "something to [your] application's data".

> What could cause such behavior?

Bugs in your app. Bear in mind that your process may terminate after starting this other activity.

Comment: Assuming the process/activity is not terminated, which is the case, what else could it be?

Comment: @Asahi: It can be a bug in your app. You might consider opening another StackOverflow question where you supply the relevant code and provide actual symptoms, as nobody can help you with no code and only "stop working" as an explanation of what is going wrong.